# installing Cloudwatch Agent with Terrafom

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cloudwatch

Does anyone know a way to install Cloudwatch agents automatically on EC2 instances while launching them through a launch template/configuration on terraform ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this can be achieved with a Bash script (assuming Linux)

Steps to consider

1. Create UserData.sh file
2. Use templatefile to link userdata.sh to launch template
3. Write userdata to install AWS Cloudwatch agent (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/install-CloudWatch-Agent-on-EC2-Instance.html)
4. Terminate/create instance
5. Check cloudwatch agent is installed, up and running `systemctl status amazon-cloudwatch-agent`

Comment: thank you. But in step 3 some manual configs are needed, and I need a completely automated process ....

Comment: you would create the a cloudwatch config.json file in the userdata so it is automated (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch-Agent-Configuration-File-Details.html)

Answer (score 9):

I have just struggled through the process myself and would have benefited from a clear guide. So here's my attempt to provide one (for Amazon Linux 2 AMI):

1. Create your Cloudwatch agent configuration json file, which defines the metrics you want to collect. Easiest way is to SSH onto your EC2 instance and run this command to generate the file using the wizard: `sudo /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/amazon-cloudwatch-agent-config-wizard`. This is what my file looks like, it is the most basic config which only collects metrics on disk and memory usage every 60 seconds:

```
{
    "agent": {
            "metrics_collection_interval": 60,
            "region": "eu-west-1",
            "logfile": "/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/logs/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.log",
            "run_as_user": "root"
    },
    "metrics": {
            "metrics_collected": {
                    "disk": {
                            "measurement": [
                                    "used_percent"
                            ],
                            "metrics_collection_interval": 60,
                            "resources": [
                                    "*"
                            ]
                    },
                    "mem": {
                            "measurement": [
                                    "mem_used_percent"
                            ],
                            "metrics_collection_interval": 60
                    }
            }
    }
}
```

2. Create a shell script template file which will run when the EC2 instance is created. This is what mine looks like, it is called **userdata.sh.tpl**:

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="==BOUNDARY=="
MIME-Version: 1.0

--==BOUNDARY==
Content-Type: text/x-shellscript; charset="us-ascii"
#!/bin/bash

# Install Cloudwatch agent
sudo yum install -y amazon-cloudwatch-agent

# Write Cloudwatch agent configuration file
sudo cat >> /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/config_temp.json <<EOF
{
    "agent": {
            "metrics_collection_interval": 60,
            "run_as_user": "root"
    },
    "metrics": {
            "metrics_collected": {
                    "disk": {
                            "measurement": [
                                    "used_percent"
                            ],
                            "metrics_collection_interval": 60,
                            "resources": [
                                    "*"
                            ]
                    },
                    "mem": {
                            "measurement": [
                                    "mem_used_percent"
                            ],
                            "metrics_collection_interval": 60
                    }
            }
    }
}
EOF

# Start Cloudwatch agent
sudo /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl -a fetch-config -m ec2 -s -c file:/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/config.json
--==BOUNDARY==--
```

3. Create a directory called **templates** in your terraform module directory and store the **userdata.sh.tpl** file in there.
4. Create a data block in the appropriate .tf file as follows:

```
data "template_file" "user_data" {
  template = file("${path.module}/templates/userdata.sh.tpl")

  vars = {
    ...
  }
}
```

5. In your aws_launch_configuration block, pass in the following value for the user_data variable:

```
resource "aws_launch_configuration" "example" {
  name          = "example_server_name"
  image_id      = data.aws_ami.ubuntu.id
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  user_data     = data.template_file.user_data.rendered
}
```

6. Add the **CloudWatchAgentServerPolicy** policy to the IAM role used by your EC2 server. This will give your role all the required service-level permissions e.g. `"cloudwatch:PutMetricData"`.
7. Relaunch your EC2 server, and SSH on to check that the CloudWatch agent is installed and running using `systemctl status amazon-cloudwatch-agent.service`
8. Navigate to the CloudWatch UI and select **Metrics** from the left-hand menu. You should see **CWAgent** in the list of namespaces.